# delegate with devise user not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, delegation

This is what I have.

item.rb:

```
has_many :comments
belongs_to :user
```

user.rb:

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
       :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

# Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model

attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :display_name
has_many :items 
has_many :comments, :through => :items
```

comment.rb:

```
belongs_to :item
belongs_to :user
delegate :display_name, :to => :user, :prefix => true
```

but `<%= comment.user_display_name%>` is returning

```
Comment#user_display_name delegated to user.display_name, but user is nil:
#<Comment id: 16, body: "fdsfsd", commenter_id: 1, item_id: 2, created_at:
"2012-03-07 23:41:10", updated_at: "2012-03-07 23:41:10">
```

Comment: is comment.user nil? if so then the error is valid

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have 'commenter' instead of 'user' in the schema.

Maybe you should have

```
belongs_to :commenter, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'user_id'
```

in your comment.rb